# Encoding only if present Dictionary of type [String : Any] in swift

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, codable

I'm a bit new to swift, just wanted to check if there is a way to encode dictionary of type [String : Any] only if the dictionary is not `nil`.

If yes, can someone share an example?

Thank you!

I'm trying to look for code with a similar implementation to default encodeIfPresent() from codable protocol

Comment: It’s not clear what you are trying to do, could you add some more context?

Comment: Doesn't the encoder skip the nil values by default?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Assume I have a dictionary of type [String : String], encodable protocol has defined a function for this use case to encode it as a JSON, but the same does not happen for [String : Any]. So, I've to write a code which encode type [String : Any] data only if it's not nil. FYI, there is a function, called `encodeIfPresent` for all data types other than those with `Any`, like `[Any]` or a dictionary of having value as `Any`. `encodeIfPresent()` encodes the value only if it's not `nil`. So, just wanted to know if there is implementation for `encodeIfPresent()` for [String : Any]?

Comment: @Larme, no it doesn't it does only when you encode it using `encodeIfPresent()` method

Comment: No Encodable and Decodable does not support Any.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson got it

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can use the if let statement to conditionally encode a dictionary only if it is not nil.

Comment: True, but there already exists functions for common data types  like encodeCondtionally or encodeIfPresent. Thus making the code more concise I feel. But, thanks this definitely works as an option.